# Simple form post always sends null to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have no idea what's the reason, it's so straight and simple, but, curiously, doesn't work. I **always** recieve `NULL` as model in controller.
Here is the code:

Model

```
public class EnrolleePlaces
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string SpecialtyCode { get; set; }

    public string Specialty { get; set; }

    public int Places { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ViewResult EditPlaces(int id)
{
      return View(repo.EnrolleePlaces.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == id));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewPlaces(EnrolleePlaces places) // 'places' is ALWAYS null
{
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           repo.SaveEnrolleePlaces(places);
           return RedirectToAction("Settings");
       }
       return View("EditPlaces", places);
}

public ViewResult CreatePlaces()
{
      return View("EditPlaces", new EnrolleePlaces());
}
```

And a view

```
@model Domain.Entities.EnrolleePlaces

@{
    Layout = null;
}

Edit: @Model.Specialty

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("NewPlaces", "Enrollee", new { area = "Admin" },
new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "AdminContent" } ,
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    // here is input type="submit"
}
```

I have over 15 controllers in my project, made by the same pattern, but only this one is *strange*

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the controller and check the `Request.Form` collection, are the fields present there?

Comment: @AndersAbel yes, it's have the right data

Comment: Try changing it to `public ActionResult NewPlaces(string places)`, does that pass the parameter to the controller?

Comment: @tomsullivan1989 it catches my `int` field

Comment: Try `public ActionResult NewPlaces(EnrolleePlaces area)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried changing the name of the parameter that your action method receives ?

for example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewPlaces(EnrolleePlaces dd) // any name other than "places"
{
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           repo.SaveEnrolleePlaces(places);
           return RedirectToAction("Settings");
       }
       return View("EditPlaces", places);
}
```